# Shorten length of character in R

Tags: regex, r

I have vector of characters something like this:

```
sampleData <- c("This is what I see i.r.o what not i.r.o",
                "Similar here a.s. also this a.s.",
                "One more i.r.o. now another i.r.o.")
```

I would like to remove everything after the first occurence of `i.r.o` or `.i.r.o`. But also in cases with `a.s` or `a.s.`.

So that the final version looks like this:

```
1 This is what I see i.r.o 
2 Similar here a.s. 
3 One more i.r.o.
```

EDIT: I corrected the gaps between the `i.r.o` and `a.s` with `gsub()` so now the expressionas are identical in each character. See example above.

Comment: have you looked at ?regex   ?

Comment: I will learn regular expressions in due course I promise!

Comment: If they all have "and" following them, `unlist(strsplit(sampleData, " and.*"))`

Comment: thanks!Unfortunately there aren't "and". I removed them from the example.Sorry this was misleading.

Comment: At this point you've probably got it =) For future reference, the 'stringr' package is really good for a user interfacing way of manipulating strings, albeit slower than using straight regex. look at `str_extract` and that should very easily get you the last step I think

Comment: James thanks.So should I close this question? Still, could not find anything similar here on SO. May be useful for others though.

Comment: I'd just leave it open. Leave it to the moderators to decide if something is unworthy of openness =) You could edit it and include the final answer / answer you're own question so people don't go to it because they see it wasn't answered yet

Comment: I still didn't figured it out completely so I will leave it open. If it gets more downvotes that's sign to close it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused because the comments above suggest that you've gotten the answer, but I don't see it.

This seems to work:

```
sampleData <- c("This is what I see i.r.o what not i.r.o",
                "Similar here a.s. also this a.s.",
                "One more i.r.o. now another i.r.o.")
gsub("(([[:alpha:]]\\.)+[[:alpha:]][.]?) .*$","\\1",sampleData)
## [1] "This is what I see i.r.o" "Similar here a.s."       
## [3] "One more i.r.o."
```

The regex reads "'(one or more of (an alphabetic character followed by a dot), followed by another alphabetic character *possibly* followed by  a dot), followed by a space and zero or more of any character, followed by the end of the line'; replace the stuff in quotation marks by only the stuff within the (outer set of) parentheses"

Comment: was letting Max get the rest of the way there =) teacher-style.. great answer with the little explanation though

Comment: Thanks! James referece to `str_extract` supposted to be straightforward but apparently...I could not figure it out!

Comment: @Max, with the info above you might be able to come up with a `str_extract` solution -- you could then post it as an alternative answer ...

Comment: @Ben. Ok, I will post solution tomorrow with `str_extract`, I'm done for today. Thanks.